# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set recycler view on a dialog box and when i initialize the recyclerview object with the layout's recyclerView id i get null ptr exception.

The error is coming on the line with arrow . PLEASE HELP

```
 Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.collection_and_friend_name_item);

   collectionAndFriendRecyclerView=dialog.findViewById(R.id.collectionNameRecyclerView);

    collectionAndFriendRecyclerList.add(new CollectionAndFriendRecyclerItem(R.drawable.ic_create_new_folder_black_24dp,"abc"));

    -> collectionAndFriendRecyclerAdapter=new CollectionAndFriendRecyclerAdapter(collectionAndFriendRecyclerList);

    collectionAndFriendRecyclerView.setAdapter(collectionAndFriendRecyclerAdapter);
    collectionAndFriendRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Have you checked if `collectionAndFriendRecyclerView` is `null` immediately after your call to `findViewById`?

Comment: yes i did with a toast message .... and it did show the toast message meaning it is null

Comment: please help if u can

Comment: So have you double-checked that `R.layout.collection_and_friend_name_item` contains `R.id.collectionNameRecyclerView` by checking the XML file carefully for spelling?

Comment: yes i did it with name

Comment: i found the error thanks a lot!!